# Remote inspect web page on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: android, google-chrome, usb, usb-drive, web-inspector

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) and I am trying to debug web pages with Chromes included support for remote inspect.
I have installed drivers from the following link: http://www.mobileusbdriver.com/samsung-mobile-drivers/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-usb-driver

I have followed the steps on https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging. But I am experiencing problems from step 3 and forward, my phone does not prompt me to allow USB debugging. The phone has been used for web inspection before with the old Chrome extension that was available before, but has been reset to factory default since.

The problem i am facing is that on `chrome://inspect/#devices` my device isn't showing up in the list. Chrome can't find my device at all.
When i look at the Device manager there are no errors, so i assume that my drivers work as they should.

I have made sure that USB debugging in Developer tools is checked, and Chrome on windows is discovering USB devices (the checkbox is checked in `chrome://inspect#devices`).

Anyone got any ideas what i might have to do to fix this?

Thank you.

**Progress edit:**
I still haven't found a fix for this. I've tried to install the android SDK, add the eclipse material to my eclipse IDE, updating drivers, updating kies, rerun the driver installation that was included in the eclipse install, and looking through my developer settings in my phone like 900 times.

Anyone still haven't got a clue of why this is happening?

Comment: I am currently trying to install Kies after finding this thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-remote-problem-debug-mode-galaxy-sii.131107/

Comment: If you run DDMS does the device show up?

Comment: Do i have to install the Android SDK for that? I have ecplise installed-

Comment: @Jari This is a long shot, but I have seen this happen in the past - USB debugging wasn't working, the device was not being recognized. At that time, the device was connected as a `Media Device(MTP)`. I had to switch it to `Camera(PTP)` to get it working. Some time later, I ran into the same issue. I had to do the reverse - switch from `MTP` to `PTP` to resolve the issue. You can try this by going to `Settings` -> `Storage` -> `Menu-Settings` -> `USB computer connection`.

Comment: That was a good tip but unfortunately, it did not work. :(

Comment: Tried to install drivers from http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows instead. Did not work better, so i'm still with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is very weird.
I talked to a colleague and he had an old nexus driver (for Samsung SCH-I515 which is a nexus phone distributed by Samsung) locally on his machine. 
We transferred it to my computer and uninstalled all the drivers i had, manually installed this driver and voila! It worked.

Why this driver worked, i have no idea. I cant complain though.

Thank you all for the help.